# How to strip of the trailing decimal point only if it has no values after the point

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to strip of the decimal point only if it has no value after the point
eg. `I100.` to `I100`, strip. but `I100.1` to `I100.1` no strip.

I tried with

```
SELECT rtrim(to_char(100.100, 'FM999999999999999990'), '.') FROM dual
```

But this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What is `I`? Why is it in the text (question description), but not in SELECT you posted? What is the source datatype? Is it a NUMBER, or a VARCHAR2?

Comment: It is just an example ... i just need to strip the decimal point.  take any floating number .. 100.100, this should remain as same.. but if i get 100 . (100 dot) , then the dot should be removed.. source datatype is Varchar2

Comment: As you've seen, datatype *matters*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the value is a string, you do not have to convert it to string once more. Just use the function [`rtrim`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions174.htm#SQLRF06104)

> ```
> SELECT rtrim('100.100', '.') FROM dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> | RTRIM('100.100','.') |
> | :------------------- |
> | 100.100              |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT rtrim('100.', '.') FROM dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | RTRIM('100.','.') |
> | :---------------- |
> | 100               |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=30d644779ebf5679043b2189266cfa26)*

Comment: Thankyou @hotfix .. it worked... didnt know it was that simple